# I am encountering while processing: ubuntu-advantage-tools :ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uaclient.config'

Tags: python3, configure

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apg apport-symptoms aptdaemon-data gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-vte-2.91
  gnome-control-center-faces gnome-online-accounts libcolord-gtk1 libgsound0 libgssdp-1.2-0
  libgupnp-1.2-1 libgupnp-av-1.0-3 libgupnp-dlna-2.0-4 libpython3-dbg libpython3.10-dbg
  librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2
  libwhoopsie-preferences0 libxatracker2 libxvmc1 mobile-broadband-provider-info
  network-manager-gnome python3-click python3-colorama python3-dbg python3-debconf python3-defer
  python3-macaroonbakery python3-problem-report python3-protobuf python3-pymacaroons
  python3-rfc3339 python3-systemd python3-xkit python3.10-dbg rygel whoopsie-preferences x11-apps
  x11-session-utils xcvt xfonts-scalable xinit xinput xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  gjs gnome-remote-desktop libgjs0g libspeechd2 python3-speechd speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 8 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (28.1~22.04) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uaclient.config'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ubuntu-advantage/migrate_user_config.py", line 17, in <module>
    from uaclient import defaults, messages
ImportError: cannot import name 'defaults' from 'uaclient' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/uaclient/__init__.py)
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-advantage-tools (--configure):
 installed ubuntu-advantage-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-advantage-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```